# HTML form not inserting data in access DB

Tags: html, asp.net, ms-access

I want to insert data from HTML form into access DB but when I call to action this `insertdata.asp` file I get errors.

```
<% 
Dim adoCon          
Dim rsAddComments   
Dim strSQL          

Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=J:\John\__Ecommerce_____\ASP\DB_Form\app_data\clients.accdb"

Set rsAddComments = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strSQL = "SELECT clientname, phone, email, lastservicedate, more-info FROM pelates;"

rsAddComments.CursorType = 2
rsAddComments.LockType = 3    
 rsAddComments.Open strSQL, adoCon   
 rsAddComments.AddNew

 rsAddComments.Fields("clientname") = Request.Form("clientname")
 rsAddComments.Fields("phone") = Request.Form("phone")
 rsAddComments.Fields("email") = Request.Form("email")
rsAddComments.Fields("lastservicedate") = Request.Form("lastservicedate")
rsAddComments.Fields("more-info") = Request.Form("more-info")

rsAddComments.Update

rsAddComments.Close
Set rsAddComments = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing


 Response.Redirect "index.asp"


     %>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? You can't insert data to a database table using a 'SELECT' statement.

Comment: Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e10'

Äåí Ý÷åé ïñéóôåß ôéìÞ ãéá ìßá Þ ðåñéóóüôåñåò áðáéôïýìåíåò ðáñáìÝôñïõò.

/insertdata.asp, line 25

which refers to: rsAddComments.Open strSQL, adoCon of the above text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird field names must be bracketed:

```
strSQL = "SELECT clientname, phone, email, lastservicedate, [more-info] FROM pelates;"
```